# java class method stubs with /* compiled code */

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just received a third party authentication library to use in my clients application. I didn't receive any documentation with it and am trying to dig through the source and see how it works. I'm very to new Java when i click **Go To** -> **Declaration** on methods in IntelliJ it sends me to a `.class` file and i see a bunch of stubbed methods with `/* compiled code */` in the methods.

I'm fairly sure this is common in Java i just don't know what to search for to learn about what exactly is going on. Any clarification would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This typically meant that you don't have the source code, and IntelliJ IDEA would just display `/* compiled code */` as a placeholder for the source code you don't have. I believe this has now changed, and IntelliJ comes bundled with a full Java decompiler plugin, and will display the decompiled source code as standard.

To better see what's going on, the best would be to receive the actual source code of the third party library.

**You should of course also get the documentation, as reading the source code and guessing how to use a library usually isn't the best way to learn.**

The second best option would be use the decompiler plugin in IntelliJ, that will automatically decompile the Java class file (note that the license for your third party library may disallow you to do just that). This will never be a 100% solution, but in most cases it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If your library is build with `sourceFiles`:

```
 task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles//look at this line
    }
```

Then you will see classes with `/* compiled code */`

If your library is build with `srcDirs`:

```
 task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
        classifier = 'sources'
        from from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs//look at this line
    }
```

Then you will see classes with full source without `/* compiled code */`

Answer (score 1):

You should really search/ask for documentation. Javadoc usually is invaluable if the method does stuff you can't guess from its name. Otherwise use a decompiler such as [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui).

*.java sourcecode* is compiled to *.class bytecode* by compilers such as javac. The compiler may optimise specific things, and a compilation-decompilation process if **highly** unlikely to yield the same source. Also, all comments should be deleted and if the code wasn't compiled in debug mode, even the variable names are lost. So: Decompilation is **not** a good alternative to handcrafted documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Refer - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/decompiler.html

Enable the Java Bytecode Decompiler plugin in settings.

If it's the first time that you're opening a compiled file, the IDE prompts you to agree to the specified terms and conditions in the JetBrains Decompiler dialog. If you click Accept, the dialog will not be displayed in the future and the appropriate code will be automatically decompiled.

[image]

After that the IDE will show you the human-readable Java code without actually converting .class files into .java files.

The yellow notification panel above the editor informs you that you’re reading a decompiled file.

[image]