# Scala decompiled code has stub /* compiled code */

Tags: scala

I use thirdparty scala library and need to research its code but I have no source code. When I try to view decompiled version, all methods are replaced with `/* compiled code */`. Both scalap and Intellij decompiler show similar result.

Is problem in decompiler or some license? Is there any decompiler in which I can see full code?

Decision from [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445385/java-class-method-stubs-with-compiled-code) for java source code is not working.

Comment: It seems that the library you are using is proprietary and doesn't expose the code.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, I could not find  the source code, but is this a problem for decompiler? I thought bytecode can be restored fully. I understand that restored code can differ from source code, but functionality should be the same. Is there any checks in decompiler? May be some meta license information in .class files?